# Need help Sql Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table with a lot of data. I already have a filter on the identity column descending and the data  are filtered with two labels. But this is less important, it is important that now I need a solution to the field  FIFTH, and when data in FIFTH is "this one"  need to that row be on top. Is there a way to programmed that?

Maybe in `Page_Load`, `GridView1_DataBound` or `GridView1_DataBinding`?

example see picture:

[Image 1 http://hamachinetwork.info/x.jpg](http://hamachinetwork.info/x.jpg)

Comment: can you show the SQL you are using the query your data right now?

Comment: Same question was put here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1717098.aspx/1?Need+help+Sql+Asp+net+C+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * 
from table
order by 
   case when fifth = 'this one' then 0 else 1 end, 
   firstId DESC
```

Comment: This works great. And now how to bold that row when is text 'this one'

Comment: That I don't know sorry. Any asp.net peeps out there?

Comment: @Priest: please get in the habit of **accepting** the best answer provided, the one solving your problem. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)